# How to insert some text within enumeration?

Tags: enumerate

I would like to write a theorem like this:

(With no assumption)

(i) result 1

(ii) result 2

With an additional assumption

(iii) result 3

How can I add "With an additional assumption" within an enumeration environment?

Comment: @Zarko I tried what you said, but "With" is aligned with "result". I figured out an alternative: Finish the first enumeration; Write "With an additional assumption"; Reinitiate another enumeration and change the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Package [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides key `resume` to continue (a named) enumeration lists. To simply continue the previous list, key `resume*` can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\roman{*})}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}(With no assumption)
\begin{enumerate}
\item result 1
\item result 2
\end{enumerate}
With an additional assumption
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item result 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
And once again:
\begin{thm}~
\begin{enumerate}
\item result 1
\item result 2
\end{enumerate}
With an additional assumption
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item result 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two theorems with text between list elements]